# Git reset hard with url

Tags: git

If I want to pull a pull request from someone without having to add their fork as a remote, I do

```
git pull https://github.com/<user>/<repo name>.git <branch name>
```

However, if there are merge conflicts, this fails, and I'd like to be able to just do

```
git reset --hard https://github.com/<user>/<repo name>.git/<branch name>
```

just as I would otherwise do e.g.

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

This doesn't work however, I get

```
fatal: invalid object name 'https'.
```

How can I do a hard reset to the OP's branch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run, for example,

```
git pull https://github.com/<user>/<repo name>.git master
```

you will see this, among other output:

```
From https://github.com/<user>/<repo name>.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

This tells you that the remote branch `master` was stored locally under the name `FETCH_HEAD`. This is not a branch name or "ref", but a so-called pseudo-ref. Nevertheless, you can use it like a branch name.

So, what you want to do is

```
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

The `git pull` command consists of two parts, and the first part is to run `git fetch`.  (The second part is to run another Git command using stuff that `git fetch` got.)  What `git fetch` normally does is to do *two* things:

1. obtain new commits from some other Git repository; and
2. update *remote-tracking names* in your own Git repository, based on the *branch names* obtained from the other Git repository.

To perform step 2, the other Git repository must have a *name* in your own Git repository.  This name is called a *remote* and you run:

`git fetch remote`

which enables your Git to do steps 1 and 2.

When you run:

`git fetch url`

your Git is quite unable to do step 2.  It can only do step 1.  So that's all it does.

To set or create a branch name (of your own) to point to one of the commits obtained in step 1, you'll need to know the commit's hash ID.  When fetching from a named remote, these are printed out during the `git fetch` operation, but with only a URL, your own Git does not *save* them anywhere.<sup>1</sup>  The easiest way to get them is to give the other URL a name, so that your Git saves them in step 2.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not strictly true: your Git saves everything it got in the special file `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  You can look inside there.  Note, however, that each `git fetch` overwrites the previous stuff, and hash IDs saved in here may not be valid by the time you look at them.  Using a remote name, and `git fetch remote`, guarantees that you'll be able to use those hash IDs.  So don't do this; use a remote name.

See also [j6t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64910679/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently trying to do:

```
git reset --hard https://github.com/<user>/<repo name>.git/<branch name>
```

does not make sense using the concept of an branch on an actual remote repository.  The `git reset` operation is inherently a *local* operation, and, as such, you can only hard reset to the regular branches, tracking branches, or the SHA-1 hash of some commit.  So, you should first `git fetch` to pull down all the branches, then hard reset from there.

Comment: Sure, I've done `git fetch https://github.com/<user>/<repo name>.git <branch name>`, but then how do I reset to that branch?

Comment: Try doing `git branch -a` to see what branches are available.  If anything _new_ came in, it would look like `origin/some_new_branch`.  Find it, and then do `git reset --hard origin/some_new_branch`.

Comment: It's not there if I do `git branch -a`, likely because I haven't added `https://github.com/<user>/<repo name>.git` as a remote. If I add it as a remote, then I'm good to go. I just wanted to know if there's a way of doing this without adding a new remote as I have a lot of PRs to review from many different people

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can choose a any local ref name using the complete refspec syntax :

```
# create 'localname' branch, or fast forward it if 'localname' already exists :
git fetch <url> <branchname>:<localname>

# example :
git fetch <url> branchname:review/pr/1234

# create or force update by adding '+' :
git fetch <url> +branchname:review/pr/1234


# you can store the incoming ref in something other than a branch
# (e.g : a ref that doesn't start with 'refs/heads') :
#   store it outside list of branches, tags or remote branches :
git fetch <url> +branchname:refs/review/pr/1234
#   store it as if it were the remote branch of some named remote :
git fetch <url> +branchname:refs/remotes/userXYZ/pr/1234
```